# Creating wordpress shortcode for button that is used on main site

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, if-statement

This is the first time I am attempting to create a shortcode in Wordpress. We recreated our theme form our primary website into a custom theme for wordpress. However I am try to create a shortcode of our buttons. The HTML code looks like this:

```
&lt;div class="button-group stacked-for-tiny"&gt;
&lt;a href="#" class="button primary"&gt;Button Name&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;a href="#" class="button secondary"&gt;Longer Button Name&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;a href="#" class="button secondary"&gt;Even Longer Button Name&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

My shortcode looks like this:

```
function buttonregion_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(
array('link' => '#', 'primary' => 'false', 'secondary' => 'true'), $atts));

if ($atts['secondary'])

return '<a class="button secondary" href="'.$link.'"><div>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></a>';

else
return '<a class="button primary" href="'.$link.'"><div>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'buttonregion', 'buttonregion_shortcode' );
```

The buttons appear correctly but our missing the spacing between lines of text. Not sure how to incorporate class="button-group stacked-for-tiny into the mix.

Comment: Do you need to add the class conditionally?  Or is the same for each button no matter what?  If the latter, just add the class after 'secondary' or 'primary' in your HTML.  If the former, just create variables with the class name as a string for the value, then echo in your HTML for the appropriate case.

Comment: In this example it would be the same for each.

Comment: Do really know how to add a class to array(
            'link' => '#',
            'primary' => 'false',
            'secondary' => 'true'
        ),
        $atts)
           );

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add to the output before your if statement:

```
function buttonregion_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(
array('link' => '#', 'primary' => 'false', 'secondary' => 'true'), $atts));

return '<div class="button-group stacked-for-tiny">';

if ($atts['secondary'])

return '<a class="button secondary" href="'.$link.'"><div>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></a>';

else
return '<a class="button primary" href="'.$link.'"><div>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></a>';
}

return '</div>';

add_shortcode( 'buttonregion', 'buttonregion_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Unfortunately nothing happened. The buttons should have moved down, but just stayed in the same spot.

Comment: I surrounded the shortcode [buttonregion] with the <div class="button-group stacked-for-tiny"> on the page and the buttons moved to the correct position. So I am gathering the return '<div class="button-group stacked-for-tiny">'; needs to be added in a different spot in the code.